# characteristic functions - Probability

Tags: probability

How to find characteristic function of real-valued random variable if I know that its distribution function is singular but isn't discrete? For example, how to find characteristic function of random variable with distribution function:

$F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0&,x<-3
\\ 1/3&,-3\leq x<2
\\ 1&,2\leq x
\end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic function is given by
$$
\varphi_X(t)=\operatorname Ee^{itX}.
$$
In this case,
$$
\varphi_X(t)=\frac13e^{-3it}+\frac23e^{2it}
$$
since the random variable $X$ corresponding to the distribution function $F$ takes two values $-3$ and $2$ with probabilities $\Pr\{X=-3\}=\frac13$ and $\Pr\{X=2\}=\frac23$.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I still do not know the basics of probability theory.

Comment: @Laki888 You're welcome! The example of the CDF that you gave is an example of the CDF that corresponds to a discrete random variable that takes only two values. So it is easy calculate the characteristic function of such a distribution. But I'm not sure if it's easy to calculate a characteristic function for a [singular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution) (for instance,  the [Cantor distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)).